# bs4 doesn't scrape corona data of china from worldometers

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

Ok this question seems weird but when I scrape worldometer for for covid data, it seems to skip china, [image: see the pic] , china is between mongolia and cameroon but is not in the dict in cmd. Please anyone can tell me why this is happening.
[link to website](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/)

```
import requests
from itertools import islice
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
url = "https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/"
r  = requests.get(url)
htmlcontent = r.content
soup = bs(htmlcontent,  "html.parser")

country = soup.find_all("a",class_="mt_a")[:120]
names = ["sno",'Country' , 'Totalcases', 'NewCases', 'TotalDeaths', 'NewDeaths', 'TotalRecovered', 'NewRecovered', 'ActiveCases', 'Serious', 'TotCases/1M pop', 'Deaths/1M pop', 'TotalTests', 'Tests/1M pop']
tbody = soup.find_all("tbody")[0]
country_info = [a.string if a.string is not None else "" for i in tbody.find_all("tr")[8:] for a in i.find_all("td")[:14] ]
covid_info = {x: {y:z for y, z in zip(names, country_info[ind*len(names):])} for ind, x in enumerate([i.string for i in country])}


print({ k:v for (k,v) in zip([i.string for i in country],[covid_info[i.string]["Tests/1M pop"] for  i in country])})
```

Edit : I changed the limit to 220 in country slicing and then it prints China at last and rest of them are in the same order. Although my problem is solved but I want to know why China was at last and others are in order.

Comment: Please share the URL and the code you have already tried

Comment: I added the code but I don't know why it was not visible. I edited the code and the link too.

Comment: With my answer below, the country's aren't in the same order as they appear on the website since the data is loaded dynamically. See [Web-scraping JavaScript page with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Edit : I changed the limit to 220 in country slicing and then it
> prints China at last and rest of them are in the same order. Although
> my problem is solved but I want to know why China was at last and
> others are in order.

China is last because, without JavaScript running in the browser, as with `requests`, you are getting the result as per the source html, where China is indeed last:

[image]

However, in the browser, the instruction to sort on Total Cases Descending is enabled and applied so China moves position:

[image]

So, if you want your results in same order make sure to order by that column  descending, and re-number the first column if including it.

As to why China is bottom of the source html, you'd need to ask the developers. It might be because originally it was a benchmark/comparator.

Answer (score 1):

To get all the data under the column "Tot Cases", you can see this example using CSS selectors to select the correct tags, and mapping the correct "countries" with "Tot Cases"

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = "https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/"
r = requests.get(url)
htmlcontent = r.content
soup = bs(htmlcontent, "html.parser")

cases = (
    case.text
    for case in soup.select(
        "#main_table_countries_today tr:nth-of-type(n+5) td[style]:nth-of-type(11)"
    )
    if case.text != ""
)


countries = (
    country.text
    for country in soup.select(
        "#main_table_countries_today a.mt_a, #main_table_countries_today tr.odd:nth-of-type(7) td:nth-of-type(2)"
    )
)


print(dict(zip(countries, cases)))
```

Output:

```
{'USA': '103,348', 'India': '21,487', 'Brazil': '83,562', 'France': '88,015', 'Turkey': '63,021', 'Russia': '36,418', 'UK': '67,859', 'Argentina': '93,395', 'Italy': '70,442', 'Colombia': '76,205', 'Spain': '80,335', 'Germany': '44,379', 'Iran': '36,401', 'Poland': '76,145', 'Mexico': '19,009', 'Ukraine': '51,278', 'Peru': '60,655', 'Indonesia': '7,202', 'South Africa': '30,374', 'Netherlands': '97,777', 'Czechia': '155,294', 'Chile': '78,706', 'Canada': '37,005', 'Philippines': '12,245', 'Iraq': '31,333', 'Sweden': '106,755', 'Romania': '56,518', 'Belgium': '92,718', 'Pakistan': '4,214', 'Portugal': '85,076', 'Bangladesh': '5,122', 'Israel': '90,055', 'Hungary': '83,787', 'Japan': '6,217', 'Jordan': '72,468', 'Serbia': '82,239', 'Switzerland': '80,502', 'Malaysia': '21,254', 'Austria': '71,729', 'Nepal': '20,953', 'UAE': '61,169', 'Lebanon': '79,956', 'Morocco': '14,107', 'Saudi Arabia': '13,420', 'Ecuador': '24,939', 'Bulgaria': '61,035', 'Bolivia': '35,595', 'Greece': '40,327', 'Belarus': '43,475', 'Kazakhstan': '21,516', 'Paraguay': '56,128', 'Panama': '89,756', 'Slovakia': '71,642', 'Tunisia': '31,930', 'Croatia': '88,016', 'Georgia': '90,131', 'Uruguay': '101,389', 'Costa Rica': '68,229', 'Kuwait': '77,890', 'Azerbaijan': '32,804', 'Dominican Republic': '28,923', 'Palestine': '59,940', 'Denmark': '50,182', 'Guatemala': '15,353', 'Lithuania': '103,661', 'Egypt': '2,656', 'Ethiopia': '2,337', 'Ireland': '53,907', 'Bahrain': '149,260', 'Venezuela': '9,148', 'Slovenia': '123,596', 'Moldova': '63,639', 'Honduras': '25,171', 'Oman': '47,415', 'Sri Lanka': '11,148', 'Armenia': '75,533', 'Qatar': '78,638', 'Thailand': '3,118', 'Bosnia and Herzegovina': '62,806', 'Libya': '27,401', 'Kenya': '3,261', 'Cuba': '14,824', 'Nigeria': '792', 'North Macedonia': '74,701', 'S. Korea': '2,946', 'Myanmar': '2,703', 'Latvia': '73,317', 'Algeria': '3,039', 'Albania': '46,087', 'Estonia': '98,543', 'Norway': '23,667', 'Zambia': '6,835', 'Kyrgyzstan': '17,356', 'Uzbekistan': '3,124', 'Afghanistan': '2,613', 'Montenegro': '159,319', 'Ghana': '2,994', 'Finland': '17,000', 'Mongolia': '28,101', 'Cameroon': '2,955', 'El Salvador': '11,767', 'Cyprus': '60,520', 'Namibia': '28,301', 'Mozambique': '2,255', 'Maldives': '130,450', 'Uganda': '1,518', 'Luxembourg': '110,913', 'Botswana': '26,383', 'Singapore': '10,588', 'Jamaica': '16,703', 'Ivory Coast': '1,779', 'Cambodia': '2,521', 'Senegal': '2,470', 'Madagascar': '1,485', 'Zimbabwe': '2,762', 'DRC': '410', 'Angola': '1,111', 'Sudan': '811', 'Malawi': '1,777', 'Cabo Verde': '56,895', 'Malta': '69,100', 'Rwanda': '2,301', 'Trinidad and Tobago': '21,735', 'Australia': '1,176', 'Réunion': '31,549', 'French Guiana': '86,406', 'Syria': '1,400', 'Gabon': '10,924', 'Guinea': '1,740', 'Mauritania': '4,261', 'Suriname': '33,375', 'Mayotte': '69,461', 'Guyana': '24,010', 'French Polynesia': '67,132', 'Eswatini': '16,054', 'Haiti': '1,494', 'Papua New Guinea': '1,859', 'Guadeloupe': '41,860', 'Somalia': '910', 'Mali': '691', 'Seychelles': '142,750', 'Taiwan': '587', 'Andorra': '178,874', 'Togo': '1,620', 'Burkina Faso': '628', 'Tajikistan': '1,366', 'Vietnam': '134', 'Belize': '32,143', 'Curaçao': '74,766', 'Congo': '2,177', 'Bahamas': '30,980', 'Martinique': '32,476', 'Hong Kong': '1,573', 'Djibouti': '11,566', 'Aruba': '103,597', 'Lesotho': '5,133', 'South Sudan': '951', 'Timor-Leste': '6,485', 'Equatorial Guinea': '6,011', 'Benin': '655', 'Nicaragua': '1,149', 'CAR': '1,446', 'Yemen': '226', 'Iceland': '19,299', 'Gambia': '2,427', 'Niger': '218', 'Eritrea': '1,492', 'Saint Lucia': '28,254', 'Burundi': '419', 'San Marino': '149,706', 'Chad': '293', 'Sierra Leone': '578', 'Gibraltar': '128,292', 'Channel Islands': '23,522', 'Barbados': '14,045', 'Comoros': '4,404', 'Guinea-Bissau': '1,900', 'Liechtenstein': '79,144', 'Liberia': '548', 'New Zealand': '543', 'Sint Maarten': '59,292', 'Monaco': '64,490', 'Bermuda': '40,351', 'Turks and Caicos': '61,777', 'Sao Tome and Principe': '10,588', 'St. Vincent Grenadines': '19,698', 'Saint Martin': '54,273', 'Laos': '278', 'Fiji': '2,176', 'Bhutan': '2,467', 'Mauritius': '1,335', 'Caribbean Netherlands': '61,607', 'Isle of Man': '18,709', 'Antigua and Barbuda': '12,795', 'St. Barth': '101,454', 'Faeroe Islands': '15,517', 'Cayman Islands': '9,148', 'Tanzania': '8', 'Wallis and Futuna': '40,279', 'Saint Kitts and Nevis': '6,161', 'Brunei ': '571', 'British Virgin Islands': '8,151', 'Dominica': '2,647', 'Grenada': '1,424', 'New Caledonia': '448', 'Anguilla': '7,203', 'Falkland Islands': '17,613', 'Macao': '81', 'Greenland': '862', 'Vatican City': '33,624', 'Saint Pierre Miquelon': '4,508', 'Montserrat': '4,004', 'Solomon Islands': '28', 'Western Sahara': '16', 'Vanuatu': '13', 'Marshall Islands': '67', 'Samoa': '15', 'Saint Helena': '328', 'Micronesia': '9', 'China': '64'}
```

Comment: thanks, but your answer doesn't include some countries like MS Zaandam. Also I solved the problem by changing the slicing value. but i want to know why rest are in order except china.

Answer (score 0):

```
# importing modules
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 
# URL for scraping data
url = 'https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/countries-where-coronavirus-has-spread/'
 
# get URL html
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
 
data = []
 
# soup.find_all('td') will scrape every
# element in the url's table
data_iterator = iter(soup.find_all('td'))
 
# data_iterator is the iterator of the table
# This loop will keep repeating till there is
# data available in the iterator
while True:
    try:
        country = next(data_iterator).text
        confirmed = next(data_iterator).text
        deaths = next(data_iterator).text
        continent = next(data_iterator).text
 
        # For 'confirmed' and 'deaths',
        # make sure to remove the commas
        # and convert to int
        data.append((
            country,
            int(confirmed.replace(',','')),
            int(deaths.replace(',','')),
            continent
        ))
 
    # StopIteration error is raised when
    # there are no more elements left to
    # iterate through
    except StopIteration:
        break
 
# Sort the data by the number of confirmed cases
data.sort(key = lambda row: row[1], reverse = True)
```

AS per https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scraping-covid-19-statistics-using-beautifulsoup/ it contains china in the data column...
[image]

so I think you can use that code and change the type of the response format.

Comment: sorry I didn't provide the link to you but I am scraping data from this [endpoint](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/) of the site. also I can't change the format because I am making api and needs to be in json.